# Getting values through relational table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database

In my app I have a page which render all the projects in the database. What I want is to be able to filter the results, for example by showing only the once in which the user is a member.

Below is from my projects controller, where I want to do exactly that (show only projects where the user is a member). What do is to first get all the projects from 'ProjectUser' where the user_id is found. Then I want to use this array to retrieve all the relevant projects from the table 'Projects', with the use of @user_is_member.project_id.

This does not work because it only give me ONE project, not all.

How can I change the code so I accomplish what I want?

**The code:**

```
@user_is_member = ProjectsUser.where(:user_id => current_user.id)

@user_is_member.each do |member|
    @projects = Project.where(:id => member.project_id)
end
```

### Tables:

**projects_users:**

```
project_id
user_id
```

**projects:**

```
id
...non relevant fields...
```

### Models:

**User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

**Project model:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users # => , :class_name => 'User'

  belongs_to :user
end
```

**ProjectUser model:**

```
class ProjectsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**Note:** current_user is the currently logged in user (which has access to all the user fields, e.g "id")

Comment: what is the current_user? is it the logged user?

Comment: @gabrielhilal: Yes, it is.

Comment: Do you have the associations set up in your models? It would be great if you can add model code here. And in your current situation, you can create a array of the project ids, `projects = []` and `@user_is_member.each {|p| projects << p.project_id}` then `@projects = Project.where(:id => projects)`. But if you have correct associations then you should not go this way.

Comment: you have ambiguous association in your user model.

Comment: @SybariteManoj is right... also, the projectuser belongs to user, but user don't have the `has_many projectusers` defined...

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it now! However, I have now updated the question with "a new try"

Comment: you are doing it wrong again, do it the way I suggested.

Comment: do it right! correct your associations

Comment: see my answer for correct associations. I will edit it with the current situation too.

Comment: look at my answer... user `has_manu project_user`, so from this association, you can add user has_many projects, :through => :projects_users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good way to associate the models. If you want to associate user to project and make one user to admin/creator then you should associate your models as:

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password
 has_secure_password

 has_many :projects_users
 has_many :projects, :through => :projects_users
end
```

Project

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :projects_users
 has_many :users, :through => :projects_users
end
```

ProjectsUser

```
class ProjectsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :role

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :project
end
```

I have added an extra column/attribute to your ProjectsUser Model that will have a string value (admin/member). And now you can get the members for a project by doing `@project.users.where(:role => 'member')` and admin by `@project.users.where(:role => 'admin').first`.

If you don't want to change your way then in your controller do something like:

```
@user_is_member = ProjectsUser.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
project_ids = []

@user_is_member.each do |member|
  project_ids << member.project_id
end

@projects = Project.where(:id => project_ids)
```

Comment: that's what i am talking about +1

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the projects for the `current_user`, you can just do:

```
  @projects = current_user.projects
```

I am assuming you have something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_users
end

class ProjectUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, :through => :project_users
end
```

Comment: This gives me the projects where the user is admin, which is not what I want in this case. :/

Comment: Ok it works like this: In the project table there is a field called user_id, which holds the creator (admin) of the project. The projects members however is stored in projects_users (through -> user_id, project_id). In this case I only want the projects on which the current user is a member, i.e through the projects_users tabe.

Comment: But shouldn't a User have "has_and_belongs_to: projects", because a user can be admin on many projects?

Comment: Tried your suggestion of associations, and to reach the projects with '@projects = current_user.projects'. However, got an error: "uninitialized constant User::ProjectUser" <- refers to '@projects = current_user.projects'

Comment: `through` is much better than `has_and_belongs_to: projects`... look to the @SybariteManoj answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have no `project_id` for some user which is somehow deleted.

Check your database that which `project_id` is `nil` by putting `puts` like statements in a loop.

Alternatively, you can use `:dependent => :destroy` on your relationship to get rid of such inconsistent data. It usually happens while you are testing and somehow delete any record but forget to delete the foreign key association relation for other table.

This can be accomplished like following:

```
@user_is_member = ProjectsUser.where(:user_id => current_user.id)

@user_is_member.each do |member|

puts "Checking the project id existence for each user member"+member.project_id.to_s

end
```

Comment: `@user_is_member` is an array. So there is no `project_id` associated with it

Comment: yes you have to iterate within this loop and for each user of this array you have to check the associated project. I have a doubt that there is no project associated for any user member and so getting undefined error.